# Joining table twice makes the query slow

Tags: mysql, join

My problem is that my query is very slow when use `JOIN` on the same table twice.

I want to retrieve all the products from a given category. But since the product can be in multiple categories I also want to get the (`c.canonical`) category that should provide the URL base. Therefore I have 2 extra `JOIN` on `categories AS c` and `categories_products AS cp2`.

## Original query

```
SELECT p.product_id
FROM products AS p
JOIN categories_products AS cp
    ON p.product_id = cp.product_id
JOIN product_variants AS pv
    ON pv.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id = 2
    AND p.status = 2
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY cp.product_sortorder ASC
LIMIT 0, 40
```

### EXPLAIN

```
| id | select_type | table |   type |          possible_keys |                    key | key_len |                     ref | rows |                                        extra |
|----|-------------|-------|--------|------------------------|------------------------|---------|-------------------------|------|----------------------------------------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    cp |    ref | FK_categories_products | FK_categories_products |       4 |                   const | 1074 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |     p | eq_ref |                PRIMARY |                PRIMARY |       4 | superlove.cp.product_id |    1 |                                    Using where |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    pv |    ref |    FK_product_variants |    FK_product_variants |       4 |  superlove.p.product_id |    1 |                                    Using where |
```

## Slow query

```
SELECT p.product_id, c.category_id
FROM products AS p
JOIN categories_products AS cp
    ON p.product_id = cp.product_id
JOIN categories_products AS cp2        // Extra line
    ON p.product_id = cp2.product_id   // Extra line
JOIN categories AS c                   // Extra line
    ON cp2.category_id = c.category_id // Extra line
JOIN product_variants AS pv
    ON pv.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE cp.category_id = 2
    AND p.status = 2
    AND c.canonical = 1                // Extra line
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY cp.product_sortorder ASC
LIMIT 0, 40
```

### EXPLAIN

```
| id | select_type | table |   type |          possible_keys |                    key | key_len |                      ref | rows |                                        extra |
|----|-------------|-------|--------|------------------------|------------------------|---------|--------------------------|------|----------------------------------------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE |     c |    ALL |                PRIMARY |                 (null) |  (null) |                   (null) |  221 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |   cp2 |    ref | FK_categories_products | FK_categories_products |       4 |  superlove.c.category_id |   33 |                                              |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |     p | eq_ref |                PRIMARY |                PRIMARY |       4 | superlove.cp2.product_id |    1 |                                  Using where |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    pv |    ref |    FK_product_variants |    FK_product_variants |       4 |   superlove.p.product_id |    1 |                                  Using where |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    cp |    ref | FK_categories_products | FK_categories_products |       4 |                    const | 1074 |                                  Using where |
```

Comment: How much categories and products are there? Keep in mind that, by using JOIN, you essentially first multiply the number of products with the number of categories and then filter out the correct ones...

Comment: Why join to cp2? You are getting no data from it. Also, when you introduce a join, the db may choose a different index usage strategy.

Comment: And please do an EXPLAIN on both queries, so you can see what is going on.

Comment: Added EXPLAIN. I get c.category_id

Comment: Why do you need to join categories to your second categories_product (cp2?)  It's no different than cp, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does running [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) on all involved tables change anything? Is `category_id` the primary key of table `categories`?

Comment: I had to read this a number of times to finally understand why you need both `cp` and `cp2`. With `cp` you check whether the product is in caregory 2, as per your `WHERE` clause. With `cp2` you join to `c` so you can also get the canonical category for that product. I'm a bit surprised that `canonical` is a property of `categories` and not of `categories_products`, but if you say so I'll accept that. So while I was tempted to agree with Emmad after reading the question for the first few times, I can now see how this would make sense.

Comment: Yes, the schema needs to be more sane for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL optimizer seems to have trouble with this query. I get the impression that only rather few products would be in the requested category, but there would likely be many canonical categories. However, the optimizer apparently cannot tell that `cp.category_id = 2` is a stronger condition than `c.canonical = 1`, so it starts the new query with `c` instead of `cp`, leading to a lot of superfluous rows along the way.

## Providing data to the optimizer

Your first attempt should be trying to provide the optimizer with the required data: using the [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) command, you can collect information about key distribution. For this to work, you'd have to have suitable keys in place. So perhaps you should add a key on `categories.canonical`. Then MySQL would know that there are (if I understand you correctly) only two distinct values for that column, and perhaps even how many rows in each. With a bit of luck, that would tell it that using `c.canonical = 1` as the starting point would be a poor choice.

## Forcing join order

If that does not help, then I suggest you force the order using [`STRAIGHT_JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html). In particular, you might want to force `cp` as the first table, just as your original (and fast) query had it. If that solves the problem, you can stick to that solution. If not, then you should provide a new `EXPLAIN` output, so we can see where that approach fails.

## Schema considerations

One more thing to consider: your question implies that for every product, there is exactly one canonical category associated with it. But your database schema does not reflect that fact. You might want to consider ways to modify your schema to reflect that fact. For example, you could have a column called `canonical_category_id` in `products` table, and use `categories_products` for non-canonical categories only. If you use such a setup, you might want to [create a `VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html) which joins products to *all* their categories, both canonical and non-canonical ones, using a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) like this:

```
CREATE VIEW products_all_categories AS
SELECT product_id, canonical_category_id AS category_id
FROM products
UNION ALL
SELECT product_id, category_id
FROM categories_products
```

You could use this instead of `categories_products` in those places where you don't care whether a category is canonical or not. You could even rename the table and name the view `categories_products` instead, so that your existing queries work as they used to. You should add an index on the two columns from `products` used in this query. Perhaps even two indices, one for either order of these columns.

Not sure whether this whole setup would be acceptable in your application. Not sure whether it would really bring the intended speed gain. In the end, you might be forced to maintain redundant data, like a `products.canonical` column in addition to a reference to the canonical category in the `categories_products` table. I know redundant data is ugly from a design point of view, but for the sake of performance it might be necessary in order to avoid long computations. At least on a RDBMS which doesn't support [materialized views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view). You could probably use triggers to keep data consistent, though I have no actual experience there.

Comment: The straight_join did the trick for me with a huge performance boost and the same result on a double table join. I thought that join was always working that way so I wasn't aware of this. Thank you very much!